# clicking event not working on clicking inner span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom

## I have dom constructed like this . there are added dynamically depending on the count from the database.

```
<div class="todo-task">
    <input type="checkbox" id='check1' />
    <label for='check1'> asdasdasdasdasd 
        <span class="todo-remove mdi-action-delete"></span> 
    </label>
```

```
<div> 
      <input/>
      <label>
           <span></span>
      </label>
 </div>
```

This is my `DOM` structure 
When I click on the  inner span element click event not working. When I keep the span out side of the div as an independent element it works fine. Any suggestions why click is not raising in the inner `span` element

This is my click `event`

```
$(document).on('click', '.todo-remove', function () {
      alert( 'Delete');
});
```

Comment: Are you stopping propagation for any of that delete span's parent elements?

Comment: No , I am not stopping.

Comment: I see there is a missing single quotes after **label for check1**. You haven't closed it well enough..That might be issue.. other than that its fine..

Comment: `span` doesn't seem to have anything inside it to `click` upon?

Comment: Or is that you are expecting to `click` on the `label` object?

Comment: Expecting a click on the span element

Comment: span with that class add's an icon over there, want to raise an click event on clicking that icon

Comment: then you probably need to wait for the icon to be loaded inside it? wait for the `$(window).load(...)` event and then attach and try.

Comment: dom is well loaded. no issues in it. issues with the click event on the span inside the label which is inside the div

Comment: If I edit your `span` and put something inside it, it works. Not really sure what could be the problem then without a demo to look at. Can you prepare a quick jsFiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vijay8059/29Louc5r/1/

Answer (score 0):

The 'span' element doesn't have a .todo-remove class, in this case the event wont be called. Try to add the class to span and add some style like this:

```
padding: 20px;
display: block;
float: right;
```

Of course, you'll change this code later.

Comment: todo-remove{float:right;font-size:1.5rem} this is the style i am using for todo-remove

Answer (score 0):

Just try this javascript. It will work for you.

```
$("label[for='check1']").click(function(){
  alert("deleted");
});
```

Comment: I can't do that beacuse CSS is well  written accordingly. which adds a label and span element with that class add an icon to the right of the label.

Comment: Elaborate? It's not incorrect to have a span inside a label, as long as the span has content and/or styling.

Comment: <label for='check1'> asdasdasdasdasd 
        <span class="todo-remove mdi-action-delete"></span> 
    </label>                                                                                                          asdasdasdasdasd  is my label text.                                                     <span class="todo-remove mdi-action-delete"></span>  - this will add an icon. want to raise an event when i click that icon.

Comment: Updated my answer. I hope it will help you. Thanks

Comment: Not good. For this small task so much css and javascript is not a good way.

Answer (score 0):

The following code woks for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lknca8f1/

```
<div class="todo-task">
    <input type="checkbox" id='check1' />
    <label for='check1'> asdasdasdasdasd 
        <span class="todo-remove mdi-action-delete"></span> 
    </label> 
</div>
```

---

```
.todo-remove{
    padding:20px;
    background: #f00;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

---

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.todo-remove', function(){
        $(this).closest('.todo-task').remove();
    });
})
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Vijay8059/29Louc5r/1/           added in fiddle with the js(i copied the whole file) i am using where it  won't work on clicking span

Comment: user1844634 What's the use of the script bellow your code, it's causing "prevent default"

Answer (score 0):

## Working code link  [Codepen](http://codepen.io/vinaymavi/pen/zGQZxj)

My be you are registered event before DOM ready. 
Please register after ready event.

```
<div class="todo-task">
    <input type="checkbox" id='check1' />
    <label for='check1'> Click 
        <span class="todo-remove mdi-action-delete">Span</span> 
    </label>  
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.todo-remove',   function () {
        alert( 'Delete');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to set the z-buffer of the inner span to -1
i.e.

```
<div class="todo-task">
    <input type="checkbox" id='check1' />
    <label for='check1'> asdasdasdasdasd 
        <span class="todo-remove mdi-action-delete" style="z-index:-1"></span> 
    </label> 
</div>
```